# Cakephp Auth Redirect out of Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, redirect

So I am working on a ajax based application. When the sessions timesout, The user gets redirected to users/login in the ajax itself... I would like to have the user redirected completely to a different layout.

I have tried with all the followings, none of them work...

```
return $this->redirect(array('ajax' => false, 'controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));

$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
```

I even set `$this->autoRender = false;`, but none of it works.

What would be the best way to have the user redirected out of ajax on session timeout?

I currently have this in my AppController.

```
if( $this->Auth->loggedIn() !== true && $this->params['action'] !== 'login'){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: If you just want a layout change (I'm assuming you already have the layout in the corresponding folder), a `$this->layout = 'the_layout_you_want'` in the `if` of the AppController doesn't work? Or am I not understanding your problem?

Comment: Hi Nuns, you got me wrong. The issue that I am having is that when the user click on any ajax link, it auto redirects the user to login inside the ajax div. it does not even take the layout.

What I am looking for is to redirect the user directly to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is render a proper response to the client, not redirect the AJAX request.

Only redirecting the current AJAX request will not stop the client from doing more requests.
Instead of redirecting it, you should - for AJAX requests only - return a value which the client knows to interpret as a signout.

If you load the AJAX request directly into a div (for inclusion into the dom tree) you can simply return a javascript which redirects the user:

```
<script> window.location = "<signout/signin>.php" </script>
```

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks... I just added below code in my AppController and it worked. Thanks...

if($this->Auth->loggedIn() !== true && $this->params['action'] !== 'login'){
            exit("<script>window.location.href='".FULL_BASE_URL."/login';</script>");
        }